# Eclipse: Attach source/javadoc to a library via a local property

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

I have a third-party library in my SVN repository and I'd like to associate source/javadoc with it locally in Eclipse. I.e., there should be some local setting (for example, an entry in the `local.properties` file) that associates the source/javadoc with the JAR file, but which doesn't introduce local dependencies into the repository via `.classpath`. Ideally I'd have

```
lib_src_dir = /my/path/to/lib/src
```

in `local.properties` and then

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib.jar" sourcepath="${lib_src_dir}">
```

in `.classpath`. Can this be done?

[EDIT] @VonC's answer is helpful... Is there a way to load Path Variables from a text file (e.g., `local.properties`) instead of going through Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked Resources?

Comment: Just added precisions in response to your comment

Comment: Just added an answer to your second question

Comment: Just added limitations to the .epf file system, in response to your latest comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe this would be better achieved through:

- the creation of a linked folder combined with
- the declaration of a linked resource

The linked resource defines a path variable which would be equals to `/my/path/to/lib/src`

[image: Eclipse Linked Resources]

The linked folder would refers to your linked resource

[image: Linked Resources]

(you can use a variable and not a fixed path, with the "Variable" button)

The variable is actually always local (to one's workspace), and will be modified through the `Linked Resources` preference screen.

The linked folder can also be... a linked *file*, thus allowing the reference of an archive through a relative path (relative to the variable).
Then this linked file (here a linked archive) can be associated to your `classpathentry` in the "`source`" attribute.

---

The problem with Linked Resources is they are local to the workspace, in the preferences.
You can **export the preferences in a `[myPrefs.epf]` file**, and then trim the exported file in order to leave only the lines containing **`pathvariable`**:

```
/instance/org.eclipse.core.resources/pathvariable.MY_DIRECTORY=/my/path/to/lib/src
```

Anyone can then import this special preference file, which will only affect the "`Linked Resources`" part.

**That solution is not very satisfying, since the `.epf` preference file can not be loaded automatically in the project**.
When I setup a project with a linked resources defining a path, I always leave a big `README.txt` at the root of my project, in order to incite the user of said project to define that same linked resources with his/her own fixed local path.

[Several bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=relative+path+linked&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&resolution=FIXED&resolution=INVALID&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=LATER&resolution=REMIND&resolution=DUPLICATE&resolution=WORKSFORME&resolution=MOVED&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=) are in progress to enhance this situation or around the [Linked Resources topic](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=LinkedResources).

Especially:

- [Exporting a project with linked resources](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=67329)
- [Relative paths without variables](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86607)
- [Have linked resources relative to workspace paths](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=33957)
- [Would like to use path relative to workspace root](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=29023)

---

[DevByStarlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735533/devbystarlight) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property/300346?noredirect=1#comment22430417_300346) the project (not very active since Oct. 2011) [workspacemechanic](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/).

> The Workspace Mechanic automates maintenance of your Eclipse environment by tweaking preferences, adding extension locations, and so on. You can use it to:
>
> - Create a consistent environment among groups as large as the entire company, your local team, or even among your own many workspaces
> - Save time setting up new workspaces
> - Create tasks that ensure your favorite new preferences are applied to all your current and future workspaces. (This is one of our favorite features!)
>
> The key to the Workspace Mechanic's behavior is the **`Task`**.
>   A task describes a simple test and an action that, when run, changes the environment so the test will subsequently pass.
>   **`Tasks`** can come in many forms: preference files, Java classes, Groovy scripts and Eclipse extensions. You can easily define your own Tasks.

It comes with a collection of scripts:

- [workspace-mechanic](https://github.com/oschrenk/workspace-mechanic)
- [workspacemechanic-settings](https://github.com/signed/workspacemechanic-settings)

Comment: This works nicely for source paths, but: (1) doc paths must be absolute, or to an archive? (2) how does one locally modify the variable?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But the .epf thing is really no better than diddling with the Preferences UI. Is there no way to set up a project so that it loads path variables automatically from a pre-defined file?

Comment: nope, I am afraid you are pointing out the limit of that system: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg22823.html

Comment: Check out Workspace Mechanic for automatically loading .epf files ... http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Comment: @DevByStarlight interesting, even though the project doesn't seem actively maintained anymore. I have added a reference in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

I just figured out a simple answer to this (in Indigo) after working on it in the background and free moments for a couple of days. The easiest way I've found is to expand your project in the Project Explorer, go into your Referenced Libraries, right-click the appropriate referenced JAR and click Properties. In there you have the options to designate a JavaDocs location. Enter the location of the folder that contains index.html and packages-list, files that are part of the Javadocs. Piece of cake!

The only problem I see so far is that I bet you need to do this in every projects that references that library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with classpath variables.

Each developer creates a couple of new variables at Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables.

Define a variable (say, JAVA_LIB_DIR) that points to a directory containing the third-party JAR (or JARS). Define another variable that points to a directory containing the third-party source code (JAVA_SRC_DIR). You can set this up how you like, but we have a structure like this:

```
common/   
  lib/
    java/       <-- JAVA_LIB_DIR variable points to this directory
      axis/
      bitronix/
        1.0/bitronix.jar   "extension" is "bitronix/1.0/bitronix.jar"
      ...
```

In your project's build path, use the "Add Variable..." option to add the library. Then you when "attach source," you'll be prompted for a variable and extension to the source code.

This way, a single, shared .classpath file can be checked-in, while allowing each developer to locate their own library and source directories where they like.