# Where are the external tools launch configurations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch, external-tools

I usually install and uninstall different versions of Eclipse for fun. I don't want to install many plugins. I prefer to start with fresh install to test the IDE.

The problems comes when I have to config all the external tools that I always use (E.g. run jconsole).

Also I want to backup my launch configurations.

Do you know where Eclipse save this launch configurations?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is a diffenrent question and the answer is contained in the answer of another question.

Answer (score 27):

As I said in this question "[Which eclipse files belong under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304)", the .launch xml files (launcher definition) are found in

```
[eclipse-workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

You can actually **move them into your project directory**:
when your project is refreshed, those configurations will be displayed in the "Run configuration" dialog.
That way, those launch parameter files can be also managed into a VCS within your other project files, instead being buried within the workspace metadata area.

Warning: **do uncheck the option "Delete configurations when associated resource is deleted" in the Run/Launching/Launch Configuration preference panel**: it is common to soft-delete a project in order to import it back again, to force a reinitialization of the eclipse metadata,... but this option, if checked, will removed your detailed launch parameters!)