# How to make an Eclipse Android launch part of project

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, launch

I have an NDK Android project, some Java, mainly C.  I followed a detailed and lengthy process (http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/) to set up symbolic debugging of the C code through Eclipse.  A debugging session is a little tedious to start up, but it works great.  Most of the detailed process involves configuring a *C/C++ Application* debug launch.  I want to make this launch part of the project, so when others import the project they will be able to use it without going through the process.

I followed [How do I save Eclipse launch profiles across workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952290/how-do-i-save-eclipse-launch-profiles-across-workspaces) and [In Eclipse, how to have launch configurations relative to the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444615/in-eclipse-how-to-have-launch-configurations-relative-to-the-project), these helped me get something that almost works.

Here's what happens.  I am in Eclipse in a project in a workspace where the launch is working.

1. I switch to a new workspace (**File -> Switch Workspace -> Other**)
2. I set the NDK (**Eclipse -> Preferences... -> Android -> NDK**)
3. In the new, empty workspace I create a new generic project (**File -> New -> Project...**)
4. In the *New Project* dialog, I expand *Android* and select **Android project from exiting code**.
5. In the Android *Import Projects* dialog I browse to the project in the previous workspace where everything worked.
6. I check the box *Copy projects into workspace* and click **Finish**

I now have what appears to be an exact copy of my project, but when I click the down arrow next to the debug icon, it does not show my launch.

But wait!  If I right-click the project in the Package Explorer and refactor to a new name which is a subset of the original project name (e.g., "Cracker" for "Crackerjack"), then the launch appears.

After having written all this, it just sounds like an Eclipse bug.  I'm using SDK 3.7.2 on MacOS X 10.7.5.

While working on this I've seen a lot of traffic about making Eclipse launches portable assets of the project.  It is sure not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Android project from existing code**, use **Import**->**General**->**Existing Projects into Workspace**.