# where are project-properties/run-debug-settings in eclipse .metadata folder

Tags: eclipse, metadata, eclipse-metadata

i'm working with eclipse c/c++ helios.

i'm using template projects with makefile with a multimedia framework. all dll dependencies are specified in makefile, so no nightmare.

i have an empty projects template, so each time i had to start a new project i have to make a new copy of that folder, import in eclipse as a makefile project.

despite of this simplicity i have to :

1) add project references

2)make a new launch configurations: 
    right-click on project > properties > run/debug settings > new..
and set somethings

i know that handle this with an eclipse plugin but i'm not interest in that.

i would like to make a little python script that copy emptyProject folder, edit .project or .cproject or whatever, and do the boring launch configuration for me. project references are in .project file,

but new launch configurations? where it is? where can i find that informations? in .project or .cproject i didn't find anything.
wherelse can i looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i worked it out due to this post:
[How do I save Eclipse launch profiles across workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952290/how-do-i-save-eclipse-launch-profiles-across-workspaces)

i found the asnwer.

the place for launch configurations is:

```
[eclipse-workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```