# How can I clean up Eclipse "run configurations"

Tags: eclipse

I set my java runtime options in Eclipse's Window > Prefs > Java > Installed JREs > Default VM Arguments.  Since this setting is sufficient for all my `main()` entry points, I do not bother with customizing the "run configurations".  It looks like nice flexibility but I probably will never need it.  I was worried that I would have to repeat my VM arguments in the run configurations and so I started to copy my VM arguments but after an experiment it seems that I do not have to.  Now I will have the opposite worry that I have some unintended customizations.

To eliminate the second worry, is there a way to eliminate the clutter visible in the Run drop down menu?  What about the "Launch configurations" visible in the JAR export dialog?  Is a run configuration the same thing as a launch configuration?  How do I eliminate the multiple launch configurations?

I am on Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu.

**Edit** After I manually delete all the run configurations, and proceed to do an export, buttons are greyed-out so I can't proceed.  When I select the launch configuration drop-down, I end up with only one choice, from an unrelated project.  I then created a run configuration for the real `main` entry point for the current project.  I expect the clutter will return as I continue to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer comes from @Francisco Puga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645038/is-there-a-way-to-delete-meta-data-on-eclipse-run-configurations)

Experimental evidence shows that deleting "launches" seems to make run configurations disappear so it would seem that they might be synonymous.

Comment: Good feedback. +1. I have edited my answer with more precisions about the launcher file location.

Answer (score 30):

One simple way would be to organize your projects by [Eclipse workspace](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#workspace), which would limit the "run configurations" list only to the project referenced in a given workspace.
Switching workspaces would reset that list to the ones recorded for the projects of the new workspace.

---

Note: the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858324/6309) regarding launches file location isn't the only location possible.
The official one is:

```
${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

But you can copy them enywhere else you want (as explained in "[How do I save Eclipse launch profiles across workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952290/how-do-i-save-eclipse-launch-profiles-across-workspaces/952398#952398)"), either by manually copying those files or by sharing them:
See "[Which eclipse files belong under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control)".

Once you know where they are saved, a simple delete is enough to make them disappear from the launcher menu.

Comment: It works after **restarting** Eclipse (at least for *Launch configuration* from **Runnable JAR File Specification**).