# Is there a way to delete meta-data on Eclipse run configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse

I may have a corruption problem in Eclipse run configurations. This happened after I dragged (or copy-pasted, I don't remember) a Java class called `MyClass` from `project1` to `project2`. Then I deleted `project1`. When I create a new run configuration the name given is `MyClass (1)`. In other words, it thinks there is already a run configuration called `MyClass`, so the new one will have to have a number appended. (**Edit:** There is no existing `MyClass` run configuration so there is no apparent reason for the appended number. In fact, I deleted all of my run configurations.)

How can I easily clean up meta-data and be able to build again with minimal manual effort?

If there is a meta-data deletion recommendation that gets rid of more than just run configurations, that probably would still be a good solution, if it does not create a lot of manual work to get set up to work again.

**Edit:** The problem might be caused by the fact that there is a launch configuration named `MyClass - project1` visible in the export dialogue. `project1` no longer exists, but this remnant lives on, tying up the class name `MyClass`. I am not sure if there is a difference between a run configuration and a launch configuration.

Comment: Had you tried, Selecting Project from the Menu Items, and then Selecting Clean.

Comment: Yes. I have cleaned and refreshed (F5) repeatedly.

Comment: +1, so that it can get required attention :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AFAIK launch configurations are stored on:

```
${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

Take a look to the existent configurations and remove those that are not interesting to you.

And restart Eclipse

Comment: Exactly! Now, this should be added to the eclipse GUI. :-D

Answer (score 6):

Open Eclipse. Follow ***Run => Run Configurations***. You will see options on the left hand side. Under the ***Java Applications*** option, you will see the list of runnable classes (the ones have a main method). These class nodes on that list are right clickable. By right clicking on your running configuration, you will see ***New***, ***Duplicate*** and ***Delete*** options. You can delete your old running configuration via delete option. To create a new running configuration, right click on ***Java Applications*** option and click on ***New*** and then configure it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there is no old run configuration named `MyClass` so there is nothing to delete.  This looks like a corruption problem so I am a looking for a meta-data fix.

Comment: Exactly! Nothing to delete there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting eclipse with the `-clean` [command line option](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm).

On windows the easiest way to do that is to copy your shortcut to eclipse and add the option to the arguments list, then start using the new shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it does not get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of the Run Configuration sidebar menu on the left side of the window is a filter icon with a downward black triangle.  See this image. [Run Configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxqOp.png)

Click on the triangle and unselect the "Filter Deleted/Unavailable Projects" item in the list.

You now should see the current and the hidden run configurations.  It is now possible to delete the hidden ones.