# How to remove launch configuration histories in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, history

Right click an arbitrary existing project in Package Explore, choose "export..." - "Java" - "Runnable JAR file", I find all the old projects in the "launch configuration" list. Those projects have already been removed from the disk, and are not visible in the Package Explore. How can I remove them from that list? I'm using eclipse indigo.

Comment: There is also option *Delete configurations when associated resource is deleted* on the Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching>Launch Configurations page. It is better to turn it on to prevent further creation of "orphaned configurations".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Under Window...Preferences...Run/Debug...Launching...Launch Configurations, you can activate and deactivate some filters that restrict what is shown in Run...Run Configurations. I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Since those projects have already been removed from the disk, there's nothing about them in the "run configurations". I only found the old projects' history when exporting Runnable JAR file.

Comment: Sorry, missed the point but in the preferences, you have a Lauch Configuration settings under run/debug and there you can activate some filters. I think it is what you are looking for. If so i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found and deleted the old configurations after unchecking the items "Filter configurations in closed projects" and "Filter configurations in deleted or missing projects".

Comment: I added a filter but still have the launch configuration of a project that does no more appear in the projects list. Interestingly, the annoying old entry does not appear under "Run Configurations…", so it is not possible to delete the old one over the GUI. Is there a way to remove it in the configuration files?

Answer (score 56):

This question seems to be well answered [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645038/is-there-a-way-to-delete-meta-data-on-eclipse-run-configurations), however, to make changes I have simply deleted every undesirable launch configuration from the below path.

```
${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/Delete all the .class LAUNCH Files
```

After deleting the files, it is necessary to restart Eclipse for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Theres another place:
`${WORKSPACe}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.ui` with the file `launchConfigurationHistory.xml`. Edit this file and remove those entries you don't want.

Comment: This is the only solution that removed my "Launch configuration" history from the **Runnable JAR File Export** window ( right click on project > Export... > Runnable JAR file > Next ). But it was applied only after I **restarted Eclipse**.

Comment: After deleting eclipse have to be restarted.

Comment: I deleted everything except for my webserver launch configurations. Restart. Then simply run or debug any project you need and the configuration will be re-generated.

Answer (score 18):

Eclipse menu -> Run -> Run Configurations... pops up the list of all viable run configurations, grouped by type. You are looking for those under Java Application.  Any of these are deletable. Delete them and they will no longer show up in Run/Launch configuration lists.

Comment: if the preferences are not set correctly, the configurations of deleted projects will not shown here. Thanks all the same!

Comment: The annoying old entry does not appear under "Run Configurations…", so it is not possible to delete the old one over the GUI. Is there a way to remove it in the configuration files?

Answer (score 7):

- Go to Run->Run configuration. Delete the existing saved projects under the Java Application.
- Run the class, having main method from eclipse. It will be automatically set.
- create runnable Jar.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Run->Run configuration. Delete the existing saved projects under the Java Application.

Then run the class, having main method from eclipse. It will be automatically set.

Now create runnable Jar.

Comment: Please do not repeat answers