# Unmatched eclipse debug configuration. How to remove?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging

In my Debug/Run Configuration icon drop down list, there is a **_memberarea_member.jsp**.

I launch the **Debug Configurations...** window, but **_memberarea_member.jsp** does not exist.

How can I remove **_memberarea_memberarea.jsp** from debug configurations?

p/s: I try to post with picture to explain better, but does not have enough reputation. Hope you guys understand the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [qwertzguy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/521538)

Click on debug/run while the drop down is displayed, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+click</kbd> on the run configuration you want to remove. A dialog will open to confirm the deletion.

You can disable the confirmation dialog in Eclipse go to

> Window ---> Preferences ---> Run/Debug --> Launching: uncheck "Prompt for confirmation when removing a configuration from the launch history".

---

From [Francisco Puga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645880/1031945)

Launch configurations are stored on:

```
${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

Take a look to the existent configurations and remove those that are not interested to you.

Answer (score 0):

Debug/Run Configuration icon drop down list show `recent file` use to run project recently. That dropdown list items is not related to list display under `Debug Configurations` dialog.