# Adding eclipse jvm arguments to version control

Tags: eclipse, version-control, jvm-arguments

In our eclipse project we have some jvm arguments that are required for the project to work. The project is connected to clearcase for version control.

How can we add the jvm arguments to version control so new developers will have them set up when they join the project (or have the rest of the team updated when someone makes a change)?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Where are theses JVM arguments needed? At the launch of Eclipse? For the compilation of your project?

If you need JVM arguments at the launch of Eclipse, you have to edit the "eclipse.ini file", at the root of your Eclipse installation folder.

If you need JVM arguments at compile time, you can customize them in Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to a launcher that you will:

- export within your current version-control workspace
- version

See [where are the external tools launch configurations in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452571/where-are-the-external-tools-launch-configurations-in-eclipse/452588#452588).
See also blog post "[Tip: Creating and Sharing Launch Configurations](http://eclipsesnippets.blogspot.com/2007/07/tip-creating-and-sharing-launch.html)"

[image]

> Select the 'Shared file' option. Select the project to which this launch configuration belongs. I suggest the launch configurations to be saved at the root of the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding it to your build.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I would create lunch configuration that can be imported later on. First create a run/debug configuration, for successful run on your local pc. If it is team project this run configuration will be fine on others machines. Then export it:  file->export-> run/debug->launch configuration and select correct one that you have created. Then you will get that exported to the file that can be kept under version control.  To import it do file-> import -> run/debug -> launch configuration and select the file.