# Unable to launch java application in eclipse after mercurial clone

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I guess this is a Eclipse question.

I have a mercurial repository with a source folder (src/main/java/) and some source code. The repository also contains a build.xml. After cloning the project into Eclipse using the Mercurial plugin I'm unable to configure a launch configuration for my project. Eclipse is unable to identify the newly cloned project as a project when setting up the launch configuration. What am I missing?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of launch configuration are you using?

- an External Tools Configuration (in which case you defnie and Ant Build with a direct link to your build.xml)
- or a "Run Configuration", meaning your repository must include a `.eclipse` and a `.classpath` for eclipse to list your project as one being able to Run.
  As discussed before in [Which eclipse files belong under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control/337317#337317), those two files can be versioned, provided they only use relative path.

Comment: Thanks. I cloned the repo and then imported it as a project from an existing build file witch did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .project file?

If you do, you should be able to use File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace.

If you don't, try File->New->Project and there are various different options to create a project from existing source.