# Eclipse CDT and Source Control

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Our team is having some difficulties with recurring merge conflicts in the .cproject (and .project) files Eclipse CDT uses for storing project information. I'm familiar with the post here: [Which Eclipse files belong under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control) but the current scenario for Eclipse CDT seems painful. Specifically, the scanner seems to create merge conflicts often in its storage mechanism and there's some sort of an item identifier number suffix used all over the place for components that constantly conflicts. I know there was a bug open to make the source control scenario more friendly. I'm wondering if that ever got fixed (we're using Indigo SR2) or if there is simply an alternate workflow that will help us out here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already found out where the conflicts occur. That is great. With that information, a workaround exists that you can use until the .cproject file format is corrected. you can [write a wrapper to diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) that checks the file name and filters out the information you know shouldn't be versioned in that file.

If you do do that, you may want to post your script to the [Bugzilla entry (this one?)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=226457) you mentioned.