# How to share Eclipse workspace and project settings across a team?

Tags: eclipse

We are a team of N developers, say. One of us starts up Eclipse for the first time, sets up some IDE preferences, creates a new project, adds source files (which are physically located elsewhere, just symbolic links added to Eclipse project), sets up build and run configurations and whatever else might be needed to flush the flow pipeline.

Now, what all files do I need to check-in to our repository, so that everyone gets those files automatically and all they need to do is launch Eclipse and they are good to go?

From my understanding, there are settings stored at "workspace" level, "project" level and then there are IDE preferences (which also need to be shared in our case, to maintain same IDE environment).
But where are these files, and are they generic in a way that if I check them in, and other folks check them out, they are all set?

Hope the question makes sense :)

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control

Comment: Thanks. Wonder why stackoverflow did not suggest that post to me as I was typing the post title.