# Eclipse debugging "source not found"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I just started using Eclipse so go easy on me ;). But when trying to debug a JUnit test case I get a dialog that states the the source is not found when I get to this line in the code in my test method:

```
Assert.assertEquals(1, contents.size());
```

I know I should probably go and try and download the source from somewhere, but I really don't want to because I have no interest in stepping into the JUnit code. I have the JUnit runtime jar so Why does Eclipse expect me to have all the referenced tools source code in order to debug my own code (seems somewhat silly)?

My main question is though, how can I tell Eclipse to skip this dialog when the source is not available and allow me to continue to debug my own code?

**[Edit]**

I've isolated the cause of this. It seems that Eclipse seems to think it needs the source when an exception is thrown by the internal JUnit code. In general is there anyway to tell it that it doesn't and just have it throw up an error dialog of some kind instead?

Comment: I think you should use 'step over' when navigating on junit methods, otherwise Eclipse would have no way but warn you there's no source. In this case, you can continue to  'step into' contents.size(), but then before actually entering Assert.assertEquals, press 'step over' instead.

Comment: That is precisely what I was doing-using step-over (f6) and it still popped this source code dialog up when the JUnit code threw an exception.

Comment: hmm, I can't observe your situation with my Eclipse environment. Which version do you use? Also, do you use Eclipse internal junit library, or provide external, your own junit.jar file?

Comment: I use Eclipse 3.4.2 with built in JUnit 4.7.

Comment: Just one thing I don't quite understand, Eclipse bundles Junit source already ... not sure why it can't find source in the first place. Also, when you say 'an exception is thrown by the internal JUnit code', does that refer to assertEquals condition not met or something actually wrong happened?

Comment: Yes,the assertEquals condition is not met. The JUnit code throws the assert exception and then Eclipse thinks it needs the source code at that point. If the condition *is* met, then it goes on its merry way with no problem.

Comment: Just completed my answer for the configuration of the project regarding JUnit sources.

Comment: Where's the setting that automatically steps over (not into) code that I don't have the source for?  If I don't have the source, it's not my own code; therefore I'm only interested in its external interface, and not interested in whatever happens in there. ~~~

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this very annoying problem for a long time but was finally able to solve it.  In my case, a null pointer exception was being thrown somewhere in Java's **Transformer.IsRuntimeCode(ProtectionDomain**) function.

I didn't really need to know about this since the exception was being caught and handled, but eclipse would pause debugging every time this happened and tell me that the source wasn't available.  As a result, I constantly had to keep pressing the button to continue code execution.

In order to prevent this from happening, I:

1. Clicked on the "Breakpoints" window
   at the bottom of the debugging
   screen
2. Right clicked "NullPointerException"
3. Unchecked "Caught"

This prevented the debugger from pausing program flow during a caught NullPointerException.

[image]
<sub>(source: [SharpDetail.com](http://www.SharpDetail.com/p/so_breakpoint.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 10):

The debug callstack will display a JUnit source code line when throwing an exception.
But you should not need to worry about that, if you do not have the source code of JUnit.

If you go back one line in the callstack, you should see the line (of *your* source code) which has caused the JUnit exception.
That should be enough to debug your code.

---

To associate the source with JUnit, you could add the `junit.jar` in the librairies of your project, and associates the `junit-x.y.z-src.jar` to the `junit-x.y.z.jar`, [like so](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/how-do-attach-swt-source-code-to-eclipse-ide/):

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130227201940/http://img241.i_mageshack.us/img241/1412/eclipsejunitsrc.png]

That will generate in the `.classpath` of your project a line like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="junit-x.y.z.jar" sourcepath="junit-x.y.z-src.jar">
```

Note: actually, there would be the full path of the `junit[...].jar` files in this `classpathentry` line. But you could also use [Linked resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property) to avoid that fixed value (the full path) in your `.classpath` file.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but it doesn't solve the issue with Eclipse, and why it feels it needs to ask for source. I was able to reproduce this same behavior with Hibernate it threw an internal exception and again Eclipse is asking for source. I feel like I missing something really simple in my IDE configuration.

Comment: +1 for your effort. But what about the next library I use? suppose I don't always have the source then what? It seems the IDE should have a provision for not attempting to ask for it if it's not there.

Comment: @James: I see your point and do not think there is an eclipse option for making it *not* asking for sources. But again, you often need to focus only on your code and not on libraries you do not have the sources. Or you have those sources and can associate them easily enough with said libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by right clicking on the project folder in the package explorer and selecting refresh. The code source was out of sync with the debugger and this corrected it. The Transformer.IsRuntimeCode(ProtectionDomain) Source not found message no longer appears.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate contents.size() on a separate line instead or set a breakpoint on the method.

Also note the junit view in Eclipse allows you to navigate the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Step Filter to avoid stepping through the ...junit... packages.  Right click on the stack trace and choose Filter Package.  You may have to turn on filtering first with Use Step Filters. ~~~

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another jar, even when I pointed to the source it would ask for it again. I was able to solve it by compiling the jar with `debug="on"` on ANT.