# OnClickListener error: Source not found

Tags: android

I'm brand new to Android development and right now I am building a simple calculator for healthcare workers. My program implements the OnClickListener class, but every time I click on the button to initiate the calculation, I get an error saying the "Source is not Found".

Here is the code:

```
public class KidneyeGFR extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView EditAge;
TextView EditSerum;
TextView Gfrtext;
RadioButton Male;
RadioButton Female;
RadioButton EveryoneElse;
RadioButton African;
Button Calculate;
double gender;
double race;
double finalgfr;
private static final int GFRCONST = 186;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditAge = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.EditAge);
    EditSerum = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.EditSerum);

    Male = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.Male);
    Male.setChecked(true);
    Female = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.Female);

    EveryoneElse = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.EveryoneElse);
    EveryoneElse.setChecked(true);
    African = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.African);

    Calculate = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
    Calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (Female.isChecked()) {
        gender = 0.742;
    }
    else {
        gender = 1.0;
    }
    if (African.isChecked()) {
        race = 1.212;
    }
    else {
        race = 1.0;
    }
    calculateGFR();
}


protected void calculateGFR() {
    int age = Integer.parseInt(EditAge.getText().toString());
    double serum = Double.parseDouble(EditSerum.getText().toString());
    finalgfr = GFRCONST * Math.pow(serum, -1.154) * Math.pow(age, -0.203) * gender * race;
    Gfrtext.setText(Double.toString(finalgfr));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the TextView Gfrtext...

```
  Gfrtext = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.Gfrtext);
```

Actually you are getting a NullPointerException, check the LogCat or Debug view  to have more specific details about your app exceptions.

Thats the big problem!!! =)

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Unfortunately, Now I'm getting this error at the project hierarchy level.
Unknown error: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the initialization of Female/African/EditAge/etc. in the onCreate method. Here you should load all of these using the findViewById method. This can easily be checked when debugging (try placing a breakpoint on the first line of the onClick method).

By the way, the convention in Java is that members and methods of an object always start with a lower case and that object names start with an upper case.

Comment: Ok, so that is not the problem. But have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any trouble ! thats an Eclipse Exception 
check this...
[Eclipse debugging “source not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960158/eclipse-debugging-source-not-found)

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at the that question and it doesn't seem to address the same issue. Or maybe it does, but I couldn't seem to use it as a solution for my situation.

I set up a bunch of breakpoints and it seems like the error occurs right after the calculateGFR method has run through.

Comment: It looks like from other posts that I need to download the Android Source code....