# Source not found message while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, singleton, factory-pattern

does anyone see anything strange in my code?
This is parser factory class which store instances of parsers. I have in text file saved informations objects in database usualy in format

```
/table/something/something
nameoftablecolumn/info/info/...

etc.
```

I have class for parsing this text file, the parsers can parse different lines. For example if the line starts /table/ i'll choose table parser calling getParser("table").
When I want to parse the views, I have some problem. I tried to find it by debuging in Eclipse, but It says me that **source is not found** and shows class not found exception in list of actions in debuging .. but no exception in program ..

This happens when I jump by F5 to the constructor of ParserFactory. 
There is code of this class:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package appInspector.input.parser;

import java.util.HashMap;


import appInspector.input.parser.database.SourceParser;
import appInspector.input.parser.database.TableParser;
import appInspector.input.parser.database.ViewParser;
import appInspector.input.parser.filesystem.DirectoryParser;
import appInspector.input.parser.filesystem.FileParser;

/**
 *     
 */
public class ParserFactory {


    private HashMap<String, IParser> parsers = new HashMap<String, IParser>();

    private ParserFactory() {
        //filesystem
        parsers.put("directory", new DirectoryParser());
        parsers.put("file", new FileParser());
        //table
        parsers.put("table", new TableParser());
        //view
        parsers.put("view", new ViewParser());
        //source
        parsers.put("source", new SourceParser());
    }

    public static ParserFactory newInstance(){
        return new ParserFactory();
    }

    public IParser getParser(String key) {
        IParser parser = parsers.get(key);
        if(parser == null ){
            System.out.println("Nepodporovaný objekt");

        }
        return parser;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have similar problem like there (similar output - mean the source not found).
[Eclipse debugging "source not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960158/eclipse-debugging-source-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the issue on my version of Eclipse but was not able to. I am on Eclipse JUNO, OSX Mountain Lion.

I modified your code a bit to test it :

```
package com.aj.spring;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *  *  
 */
public class ParserFactory {

    private HashMap<String, IParser> parsers = new HashMap<String, IParser>();

    private ParserFactory() {
        parsers.put("directory", new FileParser());
        parsers.put("file", new FileParser());
        parsers.put("table", new FileParser());
        parsers.put("view", new FileParser());
        parsers.put("source", new FileParser());
    }

    public static ParserFactory newInstance() {
        return new ParserFactory();
    }

    public IParser getParser(String key) {
        IParser parser = parsers.get(key);
        if (parser == null) {
            System.out.println("Nepodporovan objekt");

        }
        return parser;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParserFactory.newInstance();
    }
}
```