# JAVA jar debugging issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to debug web application hosted on tomcat. I have following execution flow structure.

```
public ClassA
{
    public void execute(ClassB query)
    {
        ....
        .....
        ImportedObjectFromJar = query.execute();
        ....
        ....
    }

}
```

I am using F6 to navigate through code down the line and as soon as code reach line `ImportedObjectFromJar = query.execute();` eclipse asking me to add source files of different 3rd party libraries. (`the jar file has no source attachment`).

Why? I don't want to go inside JAR file, I am interested only in my code. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: This question could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960158/eclipse-debugging-source-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I'd just keep stepping until I came out the other side into your code.  It should be able to just deal with .class files.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the next instruction after `ImportedObjectFromJar = query.execute();` and resume your debugging (F8) until it reaches your code again.

Comment: Yes, but I want step into `.execute()` method. Even if I put break point inside `.execute` method next instruction would step into 3rd party library again. :/

Comment: Then, with the breakpoint inside the '.execute' method, press F8 instead of F6 to skip third party code, and thus, get to your code.