# class not found exception during debugging

Tags: java, debugging

I tried searching for the solution in this problem and I haven't found any.

Whenever I press F5 to step into any code during debugging to try it, because I'm new to this thing, I always get "`class not found exception`" with

```
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 358
```

What should I do? I reinstalled jdk a few times now and the problem is still the same.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960158/eclipse-debugging-source-not-found?rq=1 It may help you.

Comment: Give more information about exception please

Comment: Maybe this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception

Comment: Check one of the questions from the other comments ***or*** give us more information. Like, what class couldn't be found? Is it found when you run normally and just not in the debugger?

Comment: My programs run normally but when I debug that always happens.

Comment: I think your class path wrong or your path of workplace contains some special symbol that not support in java class path

Comment: I check the class path they are the same