# How to stop Egit committing additional source folders in Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, git, flash-builder, egit, flashbuilder4

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 (Eclipse 3.7) and Git (eGit plugin).

My project has some additional source folders configured under "Build Path > Source path". When I run a commit, for some reason eGit sees these external files and wants to add and commit them with paths like:

```
[source path] fruit/com/company/Apple.as
[source path] fruit/com/company/Banana.as
```

Obviously being outside the project they shouldn't be considered by eGit at all; nevertheless I tried various patterns in my .gitignore to get them ignored, but nothing worked:

```
fruit
[source*
[source path] fruit/com/company/Apple.as
\[*
```

Using msysgit, the command `git commit -a --dry-run` does not attempt to commit these files, so it seems to be an eGit / Flash Builder thing.

How can I get these files ignored?

Comment: What gitignore patterns did you tried?

Comment: @VonC I've tried:
fruit
[source*
[source path] fruit/com/company/Apple.as
\[* ... hmm I'll put it in the question because line breaks don't appear here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step is to ensure, when you want to ignore a directory, that the path of the directory ignored ends with a `/` in your `.gitignore`:

```
fruit/
```

That would ignore `fruit` directory within the directory of the `.gitignore` (so make sure to place said `.gitignore` at the right place)

However, regarding [**linked folder**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300346/6309) (which is what `fruit` is, as the [OP Fletch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159178/fletch) mentions in the comment), `.gitignore` **will not work**.
**Linked folder should be ignored by defaults by EGit**: see [bug 333338](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333338).
The patches are written, but not yet integrated into the latest EGit release.

Update: Since [EGit 2.3](http://eclipse.ialto.com/egit/updates-2.3/) (February 2013), **linked folders are now ignored** in Egit.

Comment: Ok I tried "fruit/" and "[source path]/fruit/" too but neither worked. I'd like to reiterate that the "fruit" directory IS NOT ACTUALLY INSIDE the project in question. It's in another project linked in by Eclipse. I can't put a .gitignore file inside the other project (where the "fruit" directory actually resides) because that project is itself managed by Git.

Comment: @Fletch: "linked folder", right! I must have missed that bit in your original question. I have edited the answer to address that specific element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that we can use until we can install the latest version of EGit in Flash Builder 4.6+ (there is currently a dependency issue). Let's say (as suggested) that you have a linked resource defined in this way:

```
[source path] fruit/com/company/Banana.as
```

You could manually add all files and folders located under `[source path] fruit` to the `.gitignore` file by using the `*` or `**` wildcards:

```
**/com/company/Banana.as
```

Since the `**` wildcard matches any level of directories, you would have to be sure that the paths and/or file names are unique and cannot be found elsewhere in the project. But, since you are using a reverse-dns naming convention, this solution might be all you need.

Comment: The bug I mentioned has been integrated: since Egit 2.3, linked folders are ignored. You don't need those ignore rules.

Comment: @VonC My installation of Flash Builder 4.7 prevents updating to the latest EGit because of a dependency problem (missing bundle org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.100,4.0.0])

Comment: @VonC Were you able to update EGit within Flash Builder 4.6 or 4.7 ? Since I have a vanilla install and I can't do it, I doubt I'm the only one with this issue. The bug might have been fixed in EGit but if we cannot install it in Flash Builder 4.6+ (Eclipse 3.7) then it's not of much use to us...

Comment: I agree. I am not able to test it right now, but +1 to your workaround nonetheless.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect the fact that the problem is not in EGit anymore but is related to the fact that EGit cannot be updated in Flash Builder 4.6+ because of a dependency issue.