# Source not found in Eclipse with Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have an Eclipse problem; When I try to see some Java EE classes like `HttpSession` or `RequestDispatcher`, I get the message: "source not found" and I can press the button: "change attached source...".

But I don't know what path I should use.

How do I attach the source?

Comment: You should download source jar; then link it. 

Check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property

Comment: You should accept some of your answers, then people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how accept the answers xD, it's the arrow ? ._.

Comment: @Kai:yes there will be an arrow.If answer has helped you just mark it accepted by clicking that arrow

Answer (score 1):

That means that `HttpSession` or `RequestDispatcher`are attached to your project/eclipse as jar files and there source (java classes) are not being packed in the jar.

You can do the following thing

1. Download the RequestDispatcher or HttpSession as source jar from there web-site.
2. Install java De-compiler like [JD-decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) as a plugin in your eclipse which can decompile .class file to java.

My Suggestion is to download the source code for `HttpSession` or `RequestDispatcher` as that will be well documented.